# Yammer Sandbox / Developer Mode

Tags: yammer

I am new to Yammer Development.
My company has a Yammer network, but i don't want to use it during development (as during development, it creates junk / test posts)
Is there any way to use yammer in Sandbox / Development mode, so that it does not affect my company's existing network?
Can i sign up to yammer with my Gmail / Hotmail account for development?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for Yammer.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?